# RoR set value for textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to specify a value to the `text_area` method that will be placed between the generated `textarea` tags?

This is an example of the code I am using.

```
<% remote_form_for ... do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :message %>
      <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<% remote_form_for ... do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :message, :value => "my default value" %>
      <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the 'placeholder' HTML attribute for showing default texts in HTML fields. Thats the whole purpose of this attribute. The way to use it in ROR is:-

```
<%= f.text_area :message, :placeholder => "my default value" %>
```

Comment: This will place the placeholder in the text area however, it can't be submitted as a parameter when the form is submitted

Comment: Placeholder does not submit a value the way a true default value would when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 4):

The FormHelper [text_area](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002277) method takes a second argument to specify the method which returns the body of a textarea.

From the documentation linked above:

```
  text_area(:post, :body, :cols => 20, :rows => 40)
  # => <textarea cols="20" rows="40" id="post_body" name="post[body]">
  #      #{@post.body}
  #    </textarea>

  text_area(:comment, :text, :size => "20x30")
  # => <textarea cols="20" rows="30" id="comment_text" name="comment[text]">
  #      #{@comment.text}
  #    </textarea>

  text_area(:application, :notes, :cols => 40, :rows => 15, :class => 'app_input')
  # => <textarea cols="40" rows="15" id="application_notes" name="application[notes]" class="app_input">
  #      #{@application.notes}
  #    </textarea>

  text_area(:entry, :body, :size => "20x20", :disabled => 'disabled')
  # => <textarea cols="20" rows="20" id="entry_body" name="entry[body]" disabled="disabled">
  #      #{@entry.body}
  #    </textarea>
```

Comment: So I would write a method in a controller that returns the body of the textarea?

Comment: @Brian No, your model should handle that. For example using the method :text, would invoke the method `text` on your message model, assuming @message contains an instance of your model.

As you can see from the example, `text_area(:post, :body)` invokes the method `@post.body`

Comment: Well, I added a method to my model like so

def default_text
 "testing"
end

Then <%= :message, :default_text %>

But get the following error
"undefined method `merge' for :default_text:Symbol"

Comment: Although the documentation seems to suggest that you can call any method using `text_area(:post, :body)`, it does not work that way. The answer above did work.